# regex to match text inbetween first and last tag not working

Tags: php, regex

Below is the example

```
$lol = '<p>one</p>two</p>three<p>last</p><div>';

preg_match_all('/^<p>(.*?)<\/p>$/s',$lol,$mats);

var_dump($mats);
```

For the string above I want output like `one</p>two</p>three<p>last` but its not working for above code.But when I remove the `<div>` at the end I get the correct output.Can some one explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because there isn't a closing p tag at the last. `$` represnts the end of a line. If you use `s` modifier, `$` would match the end of a file. And also use `.*` in-order to do a greedy match.

```
preg_match_all('/^<p>(.*)<\/p>/s',$lol,$mats);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qV3lS6/2)

or

Use `\K`

```
preg_match_all('/^<p>\K.*(?=<\/p>)/s',$lol,$mats);
```

`\K` discards the previously matched chars from printing at the final. So here `<p>\K`, the already matched chars `<p>` was discarded. And now the matching pointer is just after to the starting `<p>` tag.

Comment: greedy is necessary so that op would get `one</p>two</p>three<p>last`